# Forgot lock pattern on Huawei P40 Pro, how to reset it without losing data?

Tags: lock-screens, huawei, locked-out

I forgot my lock pattern in my Huawei P40 Pro. I have Huawei Cloud but my phone IS now in airplane mode.

How can I reset my phone without losing data? Can I at least connect it to the internet with some other method?

Comment: it is impossible to decrypt the files without correct pattern, that's a high security feature and the main purpose of the lock screen